# Remove all the unwanted x axis (labels as well as empty plot space) which dont fall under facet_grid(variables)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have monthly wise information of NDVI values by **COUNTYNAME** (35 counties) and by **REGIONS** (8regions)from 2002 to 2014. Below is the script to plot boxplot (x= **COUNTYNAME** and y=**Dec**) and facet_grid by **REGIONS** and order the boxplot by Median value of Dec. In the output plot, i want to make some changes such as

1. Keep only the **COUNTYNAME** and the box plot which fall under the **REGIONS** and remove the rest. Eg. The number of **COUNTYNAME** fall in to **REGIONS** 1 is only 6. I want to remove the rest of the county information (both the x axis lables as well as the empty plot space).
2. Plot a GRANDMEAN for the variable **Dec**

.

```
  ggplot(farmsndvilongitudinal, aes(x= reorder(COUNTYNAME, Dec, FUN=median), 
                                     y = Dec, color=factor(Regions)))+
             geom_boxplot()+ 
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
             geom_point(stat="summary", fun.y=mean, size=2.0, color='black')+ 
             facet_grid(~Regions)
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to simplify the plot... Remove the unwanted counties which doesnt have boxplot....Eg. Under the region1, the box plot is available for only 6 counties. I want the script to be modified such that by removing the all other counties under the region1... similarly with other regions as well

Comment: `facet_grid(~Regions, scales = 'free_x', space = 'free_x')`?

Comment: `+ geom_hline(yintercept = mean(farmsndvilongitudinal$Dec, na.rm = TRUE), lty = 2)`

Comment: Yes, the global mean works for me...

Comment: ggplot(data =subset(farmsndvilongitudinal,!is.na(Year)), aes(x= reorder(factor(COUNTYNAME), Dec, FUN=median), y = Dec, color=factor(Regions)))+
  geom_boxplot()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  geom_point(stat="summary", fun.y=mean, size=2.0, color='black')+
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(farmsndvilongitudinal$Dec, na.rm = TRUE), lty = 2)+
  facet_grid(~Regions,space = "free_x",scales="free_x")This code works for me now.... Thanks Axeman